# How to wrap all but one template arguments using typedef and variadic templates?

Tags: c++, c++11, typedef, variadic-templates

I have a class I wrap with SWIG that is std::function proxy:

```
template <class TR = void, class ... Types>
struct GenericFunc : std::function<TR (Types...)> {
    GenericFunc() {}

    GenericFunc(const std::function<TR (Types... t)> & Action) : std::function<TR (Types... t)>(Action) {}

    virtual TR OnAction(Types ... result) {
        if(*this) {
            return (*this)(result...);
        }
        return TR();
    }
    virtual ~GenericFunc(){}
};
```

in C# or Java one can overload `OnAction` and get what he wants while on C++ side we have only one extra check.

Having a `Func` one would love to have an `Action` - a function that vould return void.

```
typedef GenericFunc<void,  Types...> GenericAction<class ... Types>;
```

So I wonder how to create an action using typedefs (not inheritance).. And [I get many errors](http://ideone.com/zXqxR1)

How to wrap some types via C++11 and typedefs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [alias template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias).

```
template<class... Types>
using GenericAction = GenericFunc<void, Types...>;
```